Import ... From ... Confusion
I read the Python3 references for the Import statement here, in which it said:

The from form uses a slightly more complex process:
find the module specified in the from clause, loading and initializing it if necessary;
for each of the identifiers specified in the import clauses:
check if the imported module has an attribute by that name
if not, attempt to import a submodule with that name and then check
the imported module again for that attribute
if the attribute is not found, ImportError is raised.
otherwise, a reference to that value is stored in the local namespace,
using the name in the as clause if it is present, otherwise using the
attribute name

For the quoted block in above, I cannot figure out what does it really say about the form:
"from A import B". In my understanding, in that case, if B is not an attribute of A, then the process will search for a submodule named as "B", if that is found, the process would search an attribute named "B" in B submodule(from "then check the imported module again for that attribute"), is my understanding to that correct or not ? Need your help.

That passage in the docs could perhaps use some clarifying. It may be worth opening a thread on the documentation group's discourse: https://discuss.python.org/c/documentation/26

It's checking the first module again, not the submodule.
So for example, from foo import bar will find the foo module and check it for a bar attribute. If there's no such attribute there, it will attempt to import a foo.bar submodule. If this new import succeeds, it should ordinarily result in the submodule getting set as a bar attribute on foo. The first import will then check foo again for the bar attribute it expects to now be there.
(The description in the docs leaves out one last step - if there's still no bar attribute on foo, then the import will try to retrieve foo.bar directly from sys.modules. This matters in some circular import cases, due to how the initialization order works out in circular imports.)

I feel what's still missing in this explanation is that submodules will become attributes of their parent module on import…

I also read the documentation(https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-import_stmt) and it says:
"The basic import statement (no from clause) is executed in two steps:
find a module, loading and initializing it if necessary
"The basic import statement (no from clause) is executed in two steps:
find a module, ...
define a name or names in the local namespace for the scope where the import statement occurs."
In above "define a name ... in namespace", it means it adds an attribute with that name to the local namespace, am I right ?

Also in above comments "namespace" is a physical thing, it is an object in Python implementation, is that right ?

@IcyBrk: Not all namespaces are the attributes of some object. For example, an import statement inside a function will assign a local variable (or variables). Function locals aren't attributes.

It's called "imported module" instead of "imported submodule", whereas "module" is A and "submodule" is B in this context.
When submodule B has been successfully loaded, it will become A.B. When the loading has failed, there will still not be A.B. If A.B is not found, the importing fails.
